# Using Schematron QuickFixes to tag individual words in mixed content elements

Tags: xslt-2.0, tokenize, xpath-2.0, schematron

I have an xml file that looks like this (simplifed):

```
<defs>
    <def>Pure text</def>
    <def>Mixed content, cuz there is also another: <element>element inside</element> and more.</def>
    <def><element>Text nodes within elements other than def are ok.</element></def>
<defs>
```

I am trying to write a Shematron rule with quick fixes that would enable me to take each individual word in defs with mixed content and wrap them each in `<w>` elements as well as wrap punctuation characters in `<pc>` elements. In other words, after applying the quick fixes I would get

```
<defs>
    <def>Pure text.</def>
    <def><w>Mixed</w> <w>content</w><pc>,</pc> <w>cuz</w> <w>there</w> <w>is</w> <w>also</w> <w>another</w><pc>:</pc> <element>element inside</element> <w>and</w> <w>more</w><pc>.</pc></def>
    <def><element>Text nodes within elements other than def are ok.</element></def>
<defs>
```

Spaces between `<w>`s and `<pc>`s are ok.

Now, identifying mixed content is easy — I think I am getting that right. The problem is I don't know how to tokenize the strings within Schematron and then apply a fix to each token. This is how far I've gotten:

```
<sch:pattern id="mixed">
    <sch:rule context="def[child::text()][child::*]">
        <sch:report test="tokenize(child::text(), '\s+')" sqf:fix="mix_in_def">
            Element has mixed content
            <!-- the above this gives me the error: a sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of tokenize-->
        </sch:report>
        <sqf:fix id="mix_in_def">
            <sqf:description>
                <sqf:title>Wrap words in w</sqf:title>
                <sqf:p>Fixes the mixed content in def by treating each non-tagged string as w.</sqf:p>
            </sqf:description>
            <sqf:replace match="." node-type="element" target="w">
                <!--how do i represent the content of the matched token?-->
            </sqf:replace>
            <!-- also do i create an altogether separate rule for punctuation?-->
        </sqf:fix>
    </sch:rule>
</sch:pattern>
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Tench

Comment: Did my answer helped you?

Comment: I am still waiting for some feedback, please tell me if my answer was useful or not.

Comment: absolutely. i'm really sorry i failed to acknowledge your answer. my bad.

Comment: How good that it was helpful :D Without feedback I was thinking that maybe you've found something wrong in my answer and I wanted to know what was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use XSL, look at this example (it is explained in code comments):

```
<sch:pattern id="mixed">
    <!-- Your context is now def => this makes easier add new def reports -->
    <sch:rule context="def">

        <!-- So now you report every def that has text and elements -->
        <sch:report test="child::text() and child::*" sqf:fix="mix_in_def">
            Element has mixed content
            <!-- What you were doing before where causing error because you were passing a sequence of text nodes to tokenize (it expects a string) -->
        </sch:report>

        <sqf:fix id="mix_in_def">
            <sqf:description>
                <sqf:title>Wrap words in w</sqf:title>
                <sqf:p>Fixes the mixed content in def by treating each non-tagged string as w.</sqf:p>
            </sqf:description>

            <!-- Replace every mixed text node of this def (this is called for every matched node) -->
            <sqf:replace match="child::text()">
                    <!-- Tokenize this text node => for each token choose... -->
                    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., '\s+')">
                        <!-- For this token choose -->
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <!-- If text is one of this (,.:) Please note that you are using \s+ to separate tokens. So a comma is only a token if it is separated by spaces -->
                            <xsl:when test=". = (',', '.', ':', 'is')"> <!-- "is" just to test results -->
                                <pc><xsl:value-of select="."/></pc>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <!-- Otherwise wrap it in <w> -->
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <w><xsl:value-of select="."/></w>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:for-each>
            </sqf:replace>

        </sqf:fix>
    </sch:rule>
</sch:pattern>
```

You'll have to adapt this to your specific problem but I think this will help you.

Comment: Interesting suggestion, @sergioFC! Do you happen to know where more information can be found on mixing XSLT with Schematron rules? I could find the most concrete pointers in the "Query language binding for XSLT 2" section of the [Schematron ISO documentation](http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/c055982_ISO_IEC_19757-3_2016.zip). There, `<xsl:key>`, `<xsl:function>`, and `<xsl:copy-of>` are mentioned as allowed content before `<sch:pattern>` elements, but so far I haven't found anything on XSLT instructions _inside_ patterns. It is working, though, so it must be allowed.

Comment: Thank you. I am afraid I can't provide doc. As I see it, Schematron specs says that you can define your own custom `xsl:function`'s to reuse them latter. See this [xsl:function inside Schematron example](http://pastebin.com/Ue5mgRCy). The XSLT code in my answer to this post is part of Schematron QuickFix spec, it is NOT part of Schematron specification itself. [Schematron QuickFix](http://www.schematron-quickfix.com/quickFix/guide.html) was created years after Schematron in order to allow XML fixes to the problems that Schematron can report, but it is an extension of Schematron, not part of it

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying the SQF context. Yet, I've tried to trim it down (see the [sample files in this gist](https://gist.github.com/rvdb/ad2dc77bf5fc33b4e02cb3e415d19888)), and it _does_ seem to work in the Schematron ns as well: all kinds of XSLT instructions are just executed happily inside Schematron patterns. For my purposes, that's just wonderful, but I would like to know whether I'm excited about a feature or a bug (either of the specification or the implementation). I just wanted to point this out to you, but will try and find a more appropriate forum to try and flesh this out.

Comment: You are right, now I see wha you're talking about. I see that any XSL seems  to be valid, but I can't tell if this should be the expected behaviour or not. Maybe it is related to the some Schematron implementation that uses XSL skeleton transformatios